# Google Cloud Messaging vs RabbitMQ

Tags: android, push-notification, rabbitmq, google-cloud-messaging, amqp

I need to use a PUSH notification system for my Android application. I know that the most known service is **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)**. But there are others messaging system like **RabbitMQ**, that is based on the AMQP standard, and that simply allows to build PUSH notification service.

So, the question is, what are the advantages (and/or drawbacks) of using **GCM**, than **RabbitMQ** (or others messaging system) ?

Comment: Have you seen this? 1.000.000 msg/second with RabbitMQ on GCE: http://blog.gopivotal.com/pivotal/products/rabbitmq-hits-one-million-messages-per-second-on-google-compute-engine

Comment: Hi, Would you like to put some light over this or some research results as asked by you in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If we are developing Push messaging with RabbitMQ, you have to write the pub sub service on android. On server side, to be connected to many more devices using pubsub you have to a cluster of rabbitmq servers. If you are using GCM, you dont have to do all those mentioned. Google does this for you.